# How do I stop the css transition that happens when the page loads [React]

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to make a transition when showing the side navigation and it works fine when opening and closing. The problem is when the page first loads the sidebar is shown withdrawning. Here is the code:

```
<div>
    <span style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }} onClick={ this.showOrHideNav }>&#9776;</span>
    <Transition in={this.state.navStanje} timeout={ 500 }>
    { state => 
    <div className={`navigacija navigacija-${state}`}>
        <a to="javascript:void(0)" className="backButton" onClick={ this.showOrHideNav }><Typography variant="h7">&times;</Typography></a><br />
        <div style={ profileDiv } >
            <img src={require('../../images/campus.svg')} style={ imageStyle } height='100%'/><br />
            <Typography style={ profileName }>Ime Prezime</Typography>
        </div>
        <div className="fadingLine"></div>
        <Typography variant="h4" style={{ color: '#FFEB3B', marginTop: '3%' }}>Neki naslov</Typography>
        <a to="#" className="linkovi">About</a><br />
        <a to="#" className="linkovi">Services</a><br />
        <a to="#" className="linkovi">Clients</a><br />
        <a to="#" className="linkovi">Contact</a><br />
    </div>
    }
    </Transition>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS I am using:

```
.navigacija {
  position: fixed;
  top: 8%;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 1%;
  background: #2B3944;
  width: 20%;
  display: block;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

.navigacija.navigacija-entering {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}

.navigacija.navigacija-exited {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
```

How can I prevent the withdrawing of the sidebar when the page loads?

Answer (score 1):

Set the initial CSS transform property to `transform: translateX(-100%);` that way it will initially be hidden

Comment: on your `.navigacija` in your css you set `transform: translateX(-100%);` and it's not hidden?

Comment: What happens is when the page reloads I can catch a glimpse of the transition as the sidebar goes away. After that everything works normally.